# SQL Query search using specific letters

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a page that returns a logged in user like: AMR/JJohnson. hpw can I write a SQL query to drop the AMR/JJ, and return anything containing "ohnson" the reason I need the second J taken off as well is because some people have middle initials there so I need to search just the last name. I tried this and others with no luck...

```
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Projects WHERE TesterName LIKE '" + Name + "%'";
```

Comment: do a simple google search this is very Basic [SQL Basics- Beginners - LIKE statementt](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-like-in-operators.htm)

Comment: How about a leading percentage sign?

Comment: This should help
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Projects WHERE TesterName LIKE '%" + Name + "%'";

Comment: Im not sure how this would be a basic search, I've Google'd for the past hour with nothing that gets the results I want. I used the name as an example, I will not know the name I need to search ahead of time, I only know the sequence they will be in. I will try leading with the % sign thanks for the suggest

Comment: @GauravSharma that did not work, debugger still shows its searching with AMR\

Comment: So basically what you want to do is take a part of the string (some might say a `Substring`) and pass that into your SQL statement.

Comment: @Craig W. yes, that would probably be a better way to describe it

Comment: @Geraldvance can you please help me understanding a bit more. My understanding from your question was that you want to get "AMR/JJohnson" when someone try to search "ohnson". Do you output to also come as "ohnson"?

Comment: @GauravSharma, my bad I was probably confusing. when a user goes to my site, I pull their win login, and that shows as AMR\JJohnson for "Jim Johnson". I need to pull all of the projects for that person in my gridview. I just need to get rid of the AMR\JJ because in the database that their projects are stored it is just first, last name. im trying to be the middle man and make a search work.. does that make more sense?

Comment: WIll domain always be "AMR" or can be different. If Domain always going to be same, you can just remove first 5 characters of the string as below. If it can be some different domain name, we can do this with Regex.

 "SELECT * FROM Projects WHERE TesterName LIKE "'" + Name.Remove(0,5) + "%'"

Comment: This approach is not tenable in the long term.  The moment the company hires, for example, Howard Johnson, your system will become confused.

Comment: ...unless you mention this issue to HR and they agree to not hire anyone with similar last names.  mmm.. mmhmm.  I like that idea.

Comment: @GauravSharma, the domain will not always be AMR, but, they will never use my site so that will not be a problem, I will be trying your response today when I get to work.

Comment: @Dan-o - I know it would not be for that reason, but I am only making this for my smaller team of less than ten, I am just glad that there are no duplicate last names, I like the HR idea though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awesome, with everyone's help I was able to get what I needed! (moved it around a bit, also i'd up vote the answers but I can't..yet)

rather than changing it after I've pulled the name one time, I changed it in the beginning. first I got the logged in user with:

```
 string Name = new System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()).Identity.Name;
```

then I had my label display the users name (also to see what it was pulling for debugging), and I used @Gaurav Sharma's answer to remove the unneeded letters:

```
getUser.Text = Name.Remove(0,5);
```

then in my SQL command text, I simply did:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Projects WHERE TesterName LIKE '" + getUser.Text + "%'";
```

and now, in stead of showing and searching AMR\JJohnson, it searches simply "Johnson"

Hope this helps anyone reading!

Answer (score 0):

The below code uses C# to create the requested substring and modified the initial like statement to only include a wild card at the front of the substring rather than at the end.

**Before**

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Projects WHERE TesterName LIKE '" + Name + "%'";

**After**

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Projects WHERE TesterName LIKE '%"+ Name.Substring(6) + "'";

Answer (score 0):

you can use the statement below to get last name from username. This statement will find index of "\" in username and will remove characters to one place more than the slash. I am adding 2 in the found index, because indexes starts from 0.

```
string query = "select * from projects where name like '%" + items.Remove(0,items.IndexOf("\\")+2) + @"%'";
```

At the same time, I will recommend **not** using FirstName or LastName as unique key. You should rather use UserID to do this. Its possible to have duplicate Last Name so that can bring back wrong records. In Case, you don't have access to userid, you should UserName (e.g.,'ARM\JJohnson'), as usernames are mostly unique.